# Javascript reads row backgroundColor as rbg but won't set backgroundColor

Tags: javascript

I want to toggle the colour of a table row. Initially I want to remember what colour the row is.

```
var bg = table.rows[I].style.backgroundColor;
```

On one particular row bg might contain "rgb(240, 255, 248)"

If I subsequently write:

```
table.rows[I].style.backgroundColor = bg;
```

the backgroundColor is not set.

If I write:

```
table.rows[I].style.backgroundColor = '#F0FFF8';
```

the backgroundColor is set.

Why does javascript read the backgroundColor as a rgb value but won't set the backgroundColor as that rgb value? How can I convert the rgb value javascript reads into a value it can write?

Please note - I don't want to start setting css styles at this point. The current code is all generated from an already very complex .aspx page.

Comment: you are probably using bg outside of the scope where it was defined.

Comment: No, because if I do this:
//var bg = table.rows[I].style.backgroundColor;
var bg = '#F0FFF8';
it works fine.
It works if I write:
if (bg == 'rgb(rgb(240, 255, 248)') table.rows[I].style.backgroundColor = '#FOFFF8';

Comment: Then maybe set up a live demo, for example on jsfiddle.net, to show us the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing intrinsically that would prevent Javascript from setting a background color using the `RGB(r,g,b)` notation. Your problem is elsewhere.

For instance, the following is perfectly valid and would set the background color of the page to a light blue shade.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(240, 255, 248)';
```

Here's a JSFiddle to prove it:  http://jsfiddle.net/4Gcm9/1

I've also tested the following and it worked just fine:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tablerow" bgcolor="#ff0000">
        <td>From</td>
        <td>HTML</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tableRow = document.getElementById('tablerow');

    var bg = tableRow.style.backgroundColor;
    tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '#00ff00';

    var p = prompt("Press enter", "ENTER");

    tableRow.style.backgroundColor = bg;
</script>
```